# Query em sql server com valor diferente consoante algumas variáveis

Tags: sql, case

Boa tarde eu tenho a seguinte query:

```
select distinct(T.Grupo) 'Grupo', MAX(G.Descricao) 'Grupo', sum(E.QtdCat*S.FactConvEst) 'M2 cativos'
from EncLin as E
INNER JOIN Stock as s
on s.CodProd=e.CodProd
inner join terceiros as t
on t.terceiro=e.Terceiro
inner join grupo as g
on g.Grupo=t.grupo  
where
E.QtdCat>0 and E.Estado in ('P','N','C') and E.Arm not in ('03P','05G') and E.TpDoc not in ('ENI','ENS')
Group by T.Grupo
order by 3 desc, 2
```

Precisava de adicionar mais duas colunas, uma que devolva o valor de sum(E.QtdCat*S.FactConvEst) quando E.Estado='N' e outra que devolva o valor de sum(E.QtdCat*S.FactConvEst) quando E.Estado='C'.

Penso que isso se faz com case... Mas não tenho a certeza até porque já tentei e está a dar valores errados.

Comment: sua query funcionar no banco de dados, copiando e colando isso você obtém resultado ou erro ?

Comment: @vitor T
Obtenho resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com um CASE se pode condicionar uma soma

```
select T.Grupo   Grupo , 
       MAX(G.Descricao) "Grupo", 
       sum(E.QtdCat*S.FactConvEst) "M2 cativos",
       sum(case when E.Estado='N' then E.QtdCatS.FactConvEst else 0 end) estado_n,
       sum(case when E.Estado='C' then E.QtdCatS.FactConvEst else 0 end) estado_c
from EncLin as E
INNER JOIN Stock as s
on s.CodProd=e.CodProd
inner join terceiros as t
on t.terceiro=e.Terceiro
inner join grupo as g
on g.Grupo=t.grupo  
where
E.QtdCat>0 and E.Estado in ('P','N','C') and 
E.Arm not in ('03P','05G') and 
E.TpDoc not in ('ENI','ENS')
Group by T.Grupo
order by 3 desc, 2
```

Comment: Amanhã irei testar ver se funcionou. Obrigado.
Logo Logo darei notícias.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!!
Obrigado :)